# How to combine different rows to one row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw some issues with the same tittle of mine but they are not really same with my problem(at least the ones that I could see) I have the below table:

```
id1     id2             column1                         column2                         column3                         column4                         column5                         column6                                      
147741  -905306891655   NULL                            NULL                            NULL                            NULL                            NULL                            NULL
147741  -905306891655   NULL                            NULL                            NULL                            NULL                            2017-01-06 15:14:10.057         NULL
147741  -905306891655   NULL                            2017-01-06 16:39:49.057         2017-01-06 16:39:49.057         NULL                            NULL                            NULL
147741  -905306891655   2017-01-04 15:09:20.057         NULL                            NULL                            2017-01-06 15:26:14.057         NULL                            2017-01-04 17:09:20.057
```

It is just part of my table, in real table there are many id1, id2 pair like above. As you can see, in each column there is only one not null value. So what I need to do is, compress these columns like below:

```
id1     id2             column1                         column2                         column3                         column4                         column5                         column6                                      
147741  -905306891655   2017-01-04 15:09:20.057         2017-01-06 16:39:49.057         2017-01-06 16:39:49.057         2017-01-06 15:26:14.057         2017-01-06 15:14:10.057         2017-01-04 17:09:20.057
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use aggregation

Comment: use MAX(columnname)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
    ([id1] bigint, [id2] bigint, [column1] datetime, [column2] datetime, [column3] datetime, [column4] datetime, [column5] datetime, [column6] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #Table
    ([id1], [id2], [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5], [column6])
VALUES
    (147741, -905306891655, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (147741, -905306891655, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2017-01-06 15:14:10.057', NULL),
    (147741, -905306891655, NULL, '2017-01-06 16:39:49.057', '2017-01-06 16:39:49.057', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (147741, -905306891655, '2017-01-04 15:09:20.057', NULL, NULL, '2017-01-06 15:26:14.057', NULL, '2017-01-04 17:09:20.057')
;

SELECT id2
    ,id1
    ,max(column1)
    ,max(column2)
    ,max(column3)
    ,max(column4)
    ,max(column5)
    ,max(column6)
FROM #Table
GROUP BY id2
    ,id1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use aggregation, assuming there is one row per `id1`/`id2` combination:

```
select id1, id2, max(column1) as column1, max(column2) as column2
from t
group by id1, id2;
```

Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: This is the same answer with the above answer. But I noticed that you both wrote at the same time almost. Thanks a lot.